# Producing a tree that has circular and elliptical nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to reproduce this image in `LaTeX` by using `tikz` (I'm not sure if this would be easiest thing to do though)
[image]

First, I tried to reproduce the left tree by writing

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.8,auto=left,every node/.style={ellipse,draw}]

  \usetikzlibrary{shapes} 
  \node {ForStatement}
    child {node {for}}
    child {node {(}}
    child {node {ForInitializer}}
    child {node {;}}
    child {node {ForCondition}}
    child {node {;}}
    child {node {ForIterator}}
    child {node {)}}
    child {node {EmbeddedStatement}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and here's what I got
[image]

Terrible... I would very much like to know how can I fix this, make the frames and draw the edges between the trees such that they won't go through any of the nodes. For the moment I have no idea what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Usually it is best to post minimal complete documents ([minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)) rather than code snippets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your tree spans too wide that a `landscape` option is used see the whole image.
Basically your code is correct. Just need to adjust `level distance` for vertical displacement and `sibling distance` for horizontal displacement. This is what I added to produce the image. However, the tree spans so wide, to see it `landscape` is used here.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,shapes} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.5,auto,every node/.style={ellipse,draw},level distance=4cm]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance = 55mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance = 18mm] % if level 2 is there
  \node {ForStatement}
    child {node {for}}
    child {node {(}}
    child {node {ForInitializer}}
    child {node {;}}
    child {node {ForCondition}}
    child {node {;}}
    child {node {ForIterator}}
    child {node {)}}
    child {node {EmbeddedStatement}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Update: Reading the OP again after several hours, addendum is added here.

The tree span is wide, hard to put them side by side unless scaling, but that loses clarity. So the two images are put vertically for illustration. Of course, the OP could change the orientation once the code is understood. Basically the second 2-level tree drawing is similar to the first one above. To connect the nodes, internal names are given, `edge[in=xx, out=xx]` where xx=angle, is used and they are listed last in the code.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,positioning,shapes} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=.45,auto,every node/.style={ellipse,draw},level distance=4cm,remember picture]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance = 62mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance = 18mm]
  \node {ForStatement}
    child {node {for}}
    child {node {(}}
    child {node (lizer){ForInitializer}}
    child {node {;}}
    child {node (fc) {ForCondition}}
    child {node {;}}
    child {node (tor){ForIterator}}
    child {node {)}}
    child {node (se){EmbeddedStatement}};
\end{tikzpicture}
% --- newly added for the second two-level tree.    
\begin{tikzpicture}
[scale=.5,auto,every node/.style={ellipse,draw},level distance=4cm,shift={(23.2cm,-1cm)},remember picture, overlay]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance = 55mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance = 40mm]
  \node {Statement}
    child {node {for}}
    child {node {(}}
    child {node {ForControl}
           child {node (fu){ForUpdate}}
           child {node {;}}
           child {node (e){Expression}}
           child {node {;}}
           child {node (fi){ForInit}}}
    child {node {)}}
    child {node (s) {Statement}};
\draw[color=blue,<->] (fu) edge[out=180, in=-90] (lizer);
\draw[color=blue,<->] (fi) edge[out=0, in=-90]   (tor);
\draw[color=blue,<->] (s)  edge[out=0, in=-90]   (se);
\draw[color=blue,<->] (e)  edge[out=0, in=0]     (fc);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest) is another interesting package for trees drawing. It's based on `TiKZ` and offers a very easy sintax. It computes all distances between nodes. 
Next code could be an starting point for your scheme.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={child anchor=north, ellipse, draw}
[, phantom, s sep = 1cm
 [ForStatement
    [for]
    [(]
    [ForInitializer]
    [{;}]
    [ForCondition]
    [{;}]
    [ForIterator]
    [)]
    [EmbededStatement,name=A]
    ]
 [Statement, name=C
    [for]
    [(]
    [ForControl
     [ForInit]
     [{;}]
     [Expression]
     [{;}]
     [ForUpdate]]
    [)]
    [Statement,name=B]
    ]
]
\draw[blue,rounded corners,<->] (A) |- ([yshift=3mm]C.north) -| (B);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]